# Call shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith during gesture

Tags: swift

Hello I am calling `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith` in swift

As my other gestures are being used, I am setting a boolean variable true or false.

I then pass the boolean variable into `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith`.

My problem is that shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith doesn't continuously get called, so my gesture recognizer feels buggy.

Can anyone help with re-calling or re-updating `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith`